# Oracle leaks threads on when closing Hibernate Sessions with Oracle JDBC driver

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, classloader, contextclassloader

We are running a multi classloaders java application using Hibernate:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.16.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc10-production</artifactId>
    <version>19.7.0.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

We noticed that even if close all off Hibernate and artifacts and `unregister` the driver we still see threads left alive that hold the classloader in the `contextclassloader`. Is there a way to shutdown those threads `Timer` & `OracleTimeoutPollingThread`?

```java
 public void close() throws IOException {
    sessionFactory.close();
    session.close();
    factory.close();

    try {
      Enumeration<Driver> de = DriverManager.getDrivers();
      while(de.hasMoreElements()) {
        Driver d = de.nextElement();
        if(d.getClass().getClassLoader() == RGHibernate.class.getClassLoader()) {
          DriverManager.deregisterDriver(d);
        }

      }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Heap dump analysis]

Comment: Are you sure that every driver was unregistered? What's that RGHibernate class?

Comment: RGHibernate is the one implementing the close() method who close all the hibernate close() methods. And is loaded in the current URLClassLoader.

Comment: @SabareeshMuralidharan yes I verified it was deregistered() but one instance is hold by a static field in the OracleDriver as defaultdriver

Comment: I guess there is a known bug for that.. static field

Comment: is there a way to close this defaultdriver somehow?

Comment: You can refer thus, https://github.com/mjiderhamn/classloader-leak-prevention/issues/8

Answer (score 0):

```java
    protected void cancelTimers() {
        try {
            for (Thread thread : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet())
                if (thread.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("TimerThread"))
                    cancelTimer(thread);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void cancelTimer(Thread thread) throws Exception {
        // Timer::cancel
        Object queue = ReflectionUtils.getFieldValue(thread, "queue");
        Method m = queue.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("isEmpty");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        if ((boolean) m.invoke(queue)) {
            synchronized (queue) {
                ReflectionUtils.setFieldValue(thread, "newTasksMayBeScheduled", false);
                m = queue.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("clear");
                m.setAccessible(true);
                m.invoke(queue);
                queue.notify();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does it also relate to the OralceTImeoutPollingThread?

Comment: `OracleTimeoutPollingThread` will be stopped when `OracleDriver` deregiestered by `DriverManager`, or you can call `OracleTimeoutThreadPerVM.stopWatchdog()` directly.

Comment: As you can see in the question we do call DriverManager.deregisterDriver(d); and OracleTimeoutPollingThread indeed stops but Timer is still alive and holds  OracleTimeoutPollingThread reference

Comment: It‘s a bug of oracle jdbc driver, It should call `timer.cancel()` in `HAManager.stop()`

Comment: ```
className = "oracle.jdbc.driver.NoSupportHAManager";
Object noSupportHAManager = Class.forName(className).getMethod("getInstance").invoke(null);
if (noSupportHAManager != null) {
 Field f = Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.HAManager").getDeclaredField("timer");
 f.setAccessible(true);
 timer = (Timer) f.get(noSupportHAManager);
 if (timer != null)
  timer.cancel();
}

```

Comment: thanks, but how is it better than the solution above?

Comment: The above solution will cancel all timers not only oracle's, the under solution need extra dependency `com.oracle.ojdbc:simplefan`, otherwise `NoClassDefFoundError` will be thrown.